# SharePoint: Only render a PublishingWebControl field when content is present

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007

I have a publishing site page layout which allows untrained staff to enter news stories into a publishing site on our intranet. The Layout contains several fields which are only required occasionally and when they lack content they leave a big hole in the page design.

Is there anyway to render these fields only when they contain content?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes - see [this blog post](http://www.andrewconnell.com/blog/archive/2009/07/17/Hiding-Empty-Content-Areas-in-SharePoint-2007-WCM-Publishing-Sites.aspx) from Andrew Connell. It walks you through writing a custom control to do this.